# Android trouble finding memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I'm having trouble with my application running into out of memory errors. I'm fairly certain I'm leaking memory somewhere, and I believe I have narrowed it down to a particular Activity and believe the leak is linked to AdMob.

To illustrate What I am seeing, If launch my app, the first activity takes up around 3Mb (it displays an image). When the second activity is loaded, the first isn't destroyed, and the total heap usage increases to ~ 7.8Mb. Once an AdMob ad has loaded in the second activity, the total heap size goes to about 12.5 Mb.

If I go back to the first activity by pressing the back button, the second activity's `onDestroy()` method is called. However, the amount of memory used by my application does not decrease at all. Even If I call System.gc() explicitly. I may be wrong, but shouldn't the amount of heap go back to 3Mb?

What is confusing me even more is that If I keep the app alive and open the second activity again, the heap size only increases maybe by 500kb or so each time I go back and fourth. It's as if something is being kept alive and reused in the second activity even though the activity has been destroyed.

I've simplified my code here to see if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong. I have also had a look at the dump files using MAT but I'm not too sure on what I'm looking at and haven't found much of use.

**My first(default) activity**

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
     }


     public void startSelectionPage(View v){
         Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, ImageSelectActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/startpage" >

        <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/pb"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/playbutton"
          android:onClick="startSelectionPage"          
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**ImageSelectActivity**

```
public class ImageSelectActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

         setContentView(R.layout.selectionpage);    

         ((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery))
         .setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(), 150));     
    }

     @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
        AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        ad.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();
     }
 }

 class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context myContext;
    private int imageBackground;
    private int galleryHeight;

    private int[] myImageIds = {
                R.drawable.canyonthumb,
                R.drawable.yosemitethumb,
                R.drawable.flowerthumb,
                R.drawable.squirrelthumb

    };

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, int galleryHeight) { 
        this.myContext = c;
        TypedArray ta = c.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
        imageBackground = ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
        ta.recycle();
        this.galleryHeight = galleryHeight;
    }

    public int getCount() { return this.myImageIds.length; }
    public Object getItem(int position) { return position; }
    public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(myContext);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(galleryHeight,galleryHeight));
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);
        imageView.setImageResource(this.myImageIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

**selectionpage.xml**

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/chooseanimage"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlayout1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

                    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="60dp"
                         ads:adUnitId="----"
                         ads:adSize="IAB_BANNER"
                         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,---"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                         />

                    <Gallery
                        android:id="@+id/gallery"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
                        />

        </RelativeLayout>   
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Read the documentation of `System.gc()`. Its not a "do it now" its more like a "it would be nice if you do it now, if not I apologize for asking"

Comment: thanks but I'm fairly certain the GC will be called at some point. Especially if i've restarted the activity many times and the heap size keeps going up and up

Comment: It will run, of course, but it is not defined that the GC will run as soon as you call `gc()`. Quote: `There is no guarantee that the garbage collector will actually be run.`

Comment: Hmm.. When `onDestroy` is called are you `recycling` your bitmaps ?  If i remember correctly the bitmaps are handled in such a way that the garbage collector can't free up the memory that they use

Comment: I'm not recycling the bitmaps myself but I don't think that's the problem. I have messed around with MAT some more and found out the following. If I have an advert on my second activity, when going back to the first, my second Activity remains in memory. Without ads, the second Activity is correctly destroyed. The problem comes from the ad, and I must not be destroying it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe I ever had a memory leak. The issue was with the GC, which seemingly allowed objects to remain in memory for much longer that I expected. If I try the code on a 16Mb emulator, the GC works much more aggressively.

Another thing I did not expect was the high memory usage of AdMob. Adding adverts to one of my activities has resulted in ~8MB of heap being used.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question: [android memory management in activity lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001682/android-memory-management-in-activity-lifecycle). Its not the exact same question as yours but the answers contain the information I believe you are looking for.

So rather then typing up an long explanation of the relationship between memory, the garbage collector and the activity life cycle I'm going to refer you to the above question.

Comment: I've have a read but I'm not sure it answers my question? How does it explain the large amount of memory that remains after the activity is destroyed

Comment: Are you sure the `onFinish` is getting called for your activity? Having an activity go out of scope doesn't always mean its destroyed.

Comment: Do you mean `onDestroy`? because that is definitely getting called

Comment: Are you holding on to any members of the Activity class? Do you retain a reference to any children views or objects in a different Activity?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got the code right but here is what I think:

In `ImageSelectActivity` you create a new object of `ImageAdapter`. It is an anonymous object as you use `new` in the `setAdapter()` call.

The `ImageAdapter` object will not be destroyed as long as your activity lives. You might set the adapter of you activity to null in the `onDestroy()`

A very good blog post is about your topic: [avoiding memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

The third point at the end:

> Avoid non-static inner classes in an activity if you don't control
>   their life cycle, use a static inner class and make a weak reference
>   to the activity inside. The solution to this issue is to use a static
>   inner class with a WeakReference to the outer class, as done in
>   ViewRoot and its W inner class for instance

Thats what you should do.

Comment: I tried what you suggested. Infact, I tried removing the `ImageAdapater` class altogether. With that class gone, I ran my app, opened the second activity and closed it. I then took a memory dump and found that the `ImageSelectActivity` remained. If I look at the 'path to GC roots' of the activity, the top element is the adView. I don't think the adView is being destroyed? and that it holds a reference to the context? Thanks for the help