# Android's activity lifecycle after coming out of sleep

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

If an activity is being shown on the screen and has a button with a click listener attached to it, that gets attached to the button during the onCreate method, and then the device goes into sleep mode (or the user taps on the power button to turn off the screen), when the screen comes back on the activity is still visible as it was prior to going into sleep mode.

The onResume gets called, which is documented as part of the lifecycle for an activity. What I don't understand is why the onCreate doesn't get called again. How is it possible for the button's click listener to even function after coming out of sleep mode? You would think that Android has destroyed all running processes attached to the activity which includes the button's click listener.

Comment: ultimately what u want!

Comment: Sure, it's what I want but my question is what is going on. If the handlers and threads aren't destroyed, I can only assume that Android (or the hardware) is capable of "pausing" the state of all processes (except one's like the AlarmManager) and then "unpausing" this state when the device comes out of sleep mode. I suppose that this is only possible by the architecture of the device in order to conserve battery. What is really interesting is that if this is true, why don't background services remain alive when coming out of sleep mode. They can and do in fact get killed during sleep mode.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by, why doesn't the `onCreate()` get called again?

Simple answer: your activity is not being destroyed when the screen goes off, so there is no reason for `onCreate()` to be called again.

When the phone's screen is turned off, the activity's `onPause()` callback is called, followed by `onStop()`. However, just because it reaches `onStop()` does not mean that it will always reach `onDestroy()`. At least to my understanding, Android's OS attempts to keep as much of its memory used as possible so that apps will load back up faster, etc (this is a real over simplification, but I believe that is the general idea). That means that your activity still exists in memory when the screen goes off (at least at the beginning). Only when the system really needs the resources that your activity holds will it call your activity's `onDestroy()`. That is why your button click listener still works when you turn the screen off. Your activity still exists in memory, which means that your button listener is also still registered.

I think it's important to point out that sleep mode and turning off the screen are not the same thing. When you turn the screen off, it may or may not go into sleep mode right away. When the screen goes off but it doesn't go into sleep mode yet, the cpu is still working and the service is still running. When the phone goes into sleep mode it powers down the CPU, essentially "freezing" all processes, and as a result all `services` also. Using wakelocks prevents the phone from going into sleep mode, which is why services will still run while the phone's screen is off for an extended period of time. If you haven't read it yet, the [`Service` reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle)  has some pretty good info. It also discusses its lifecycle and how Android prioritizes its memory usage.

Comment: Your explanation does not explain why services are killed when the screen is off for a long enough period. Forget about the wakelock as that has nothing to do with the explanation as to why an activity's process remains intact and is restored when the screen comes back on.

Comment: When your device is in need for memory it can kill your entire process. This includes your activity and services. As said in this answer, this is not guaranteed to happen everytime the device is going to sleep. In contrary to what was said in this answer, onDestroy() might not be called when the process is killed.

Answer (score 1):

Android's activity lifecycle is extremly complicated and even [Romain Guy states he doesn't understand it fully](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325418001) after many years of core development on android. You can assume that Android OS can interfere with your Activities lifecycle how it may seem fit when it's in background. The [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) represents the actual behaviour only very roughly, mostly I got my understanding through experience and trail and error.

In your case if you send your activity in background, if android has RAM available it trys to keep your activity in RAM, so it's going through onPause and onStop. Now this state can persist until you return to your app, then it will go through onStart and onResume, since all your references/fields you created onCreate still exists and can be "reused". On the other hand if the OS decides to it needs more memory it can destroy your activty and will be open for garbage collection and also will go through the onDestroy() lifecycle. The next time you reopen your app a new activity will be created with the state saved onSaveInstanceState() and the whole lifecycle from onCreate() will be run through

With services it's the same thing. Usally service SHOULD not run over long time, they also should stop themselfs immediatelyafter they are done. So if the OS finds a service that runs over long time in the background it trys to get rid of it to save battery / ram after an abitrary amound of time (and perhaps other parameters are included in this decision). On the other hand IF you need a long running service you need to manually keep a wakelock to  sginal the OS "I need this done no matter what".

Comment: Any update for that link to Romain's statement? Would be such a gem to read, but alas, we can't!

Answer (score 0):

When you press power button or home button ,android OS put your current activity onto back stack,
Reason why onCreate doesnt get called again is,it is specifically made to create views and to do one time memory operation like loading your xml layout into activity.The system works such as you dont have to allocate memories each time you come on that page instead only when you created the page.onResume gets called because you are resuming back to the same activity.
Memroy Managment is very crucial in Android as it is a mobile operating system.

Comment: Please ask for more clarification if you need,or if you think this answer doesn't target your doubt.

Comment: I don't think pressing home or pressing the power button does put the current activity on the back stack.

Comment: If onPause method gets called while doing this,than it means DVM is
putting current Activity in backstack.
May be this link solves your doubt,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001682/android-memory-management-in-activity-lifecycle
see Michael's answer regarding activity life cycle and memory management.

Answer (score 0):

short answer:
`onCreate()` gets called when a `Activity` gets created.
the behavior for a device going into sleep and comming back is defined as `onPause()` and `onResume()` call. device sleeping will not kill the app or the activity - state keeps (nearly) the same.

Answer (score 0):

@AndroidDev you will get clarity of this question, if you know which methods are calling at what time. below is the method called list at the different scenario

1)when we start activity nothing but calling `startActivity(intent)` this time

```
onCreate()
onStart()
onResume()
```

2)how many ways activity goes in sleep mode?
a)when we pressed lock button it will goes in  sleep mode and below methods called
b)when we pressed overview button it will goes in  sleep mode and below methods called
c)when we start another activity from present activity it will goes in sleep mode and below methods called

```
onPause()
onStop()
```

3)how many ways activity destroy
a)if we called finish() method it will called below methods
b)if we click back button it will called below methods

```
onPause()
onStop()
onDestroy()
```

so when ever activity going in sleep mode it's not calling `onDestory()` method, that why when your coming back from sleep mode your activity not calling `onCreate` method.
`onCreate()` will called only first time when you called `startActivity()` or if you destroy activity calling `finish()` or back button pressed in this both condition `destroy()` method will called.